# c#, WinApi: can't select item in combobox or additem to the listview using WM_SETTEXT and other messages

Tags: c#, winapi

some backstory: there is an application with the small listbox:

[image: Image of the Listbox]

Items are added throught the "+" button

[image: Image of the added row]

At this point you can directly change text in the item or press "*" button for another dialog to appear and edit there:

[image: Image of the second dialog]

This is how Listview (Main SysListView control and first 3 fields in the ListView are underlined on the image, ***want to mension that the first filed within this ListView is a Combobox***) looking in the Spy++:

[image: Image of the Listbox in Spy++]

This is how the second dialog (Image 2) (Combobox control and its 'Edit' window are underlined on the image) looking in the Spy++:

[image: Image of the Dialog in Spy++]

What i can do: Find all the needed handles, click both "+" and "*" button, fill both textboxes in the dialog (3).

The problem is: I can't choose an item in the **Combobox** of the dialog (3) or add item directly to the **ListView** without using dialog (3).

For choosing item in the **Combobox** i used *WM_SETTEXT* with marshaling lpsz...and using this method the text is set in the combobox, but upon clicking "OK" in the dialog this text is not being saved and added to the ListView. I also used *SETCURSEL* and again - text being set in the combobox without being saved and added to the lsitbox.
Though i solved the problem by emulating human behavior - posting *KEYDOWN/KEYUP* event it doesnt satisfy me, because i am sure there is a more advanced method, and also i am kinda curious why this method works and others fail.

For adding item directly into the **ListView** i tried same stuff but this time without any success.

**SO, summarizing my questions:**

***1) How can item be added to the Listview.***

***2) Why *SETTEXT/SETCURSEL* are not working on Combobox though the text is being added.***

For Example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Test");
SendMessage(Combobox_Handle, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, sb);
```

This will add the "test" to the combobox but upon clicking OK on the dialog the text will not save. But emulating human behavior and using WM_KEYUP is working.

***3) Didnt mension this problem, but why doesnt *WM_SETTEXT* work on masked textboxes, i had to cycle through my string and put each charachter with *WM_CHAR*.***

For Example:

Textbox looks like this: "    -    -      ", if i use

```
SendMessage(Combobox_Handle, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, "000-000-000000")
```

the text will set, but upon clicking on the textbox it disappears, so i had to do this:

```
string s = "005006012567";
foreach (char c in s)
{
    PostMessage(TextBox_Handle, WM_CHAR, wParam_Dictionary[c],lParam_Dictionary[c]);
}
```

This works perfectly, but i want to ask if this method is any good, and if there are any other ways to do this.

Can't provide any of the code because the project is at work. I am working on this for about 2 weeks and searched the crap out of the internet without success.

Comment: You'll need to provide code. A [mcve] please.

Comment: ListBox and [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/list-view-controls-overview) are two different things. I don't completely understand the question but it looks like you need ["UI Automation"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/invoke-a-control-using-ui-automation) to interact with another program. ListView needs `LVM_INSERTITEM` to insert an item, it's might bee too much headache with managed code.

Comment: @David Heffernan, i ll provide it tomorrow.

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani, my bad - ofc its a ListView. I ll try LVM_INSERTITEM. I ll read about about UI Automation, thanks.

Comment: @David Heffernan Added some code in the "Questions" area at the end of my post.

Comment: Also if this is external process, you have to get a process handle, use `VirtualAllocEx` to allocate memory for `LVITEM` and text, use `WriteProcessMemory` to copy `LVITEM` and text to memory, then send `LVM_INSERTITEM` message. Then free the memory and close the handles. UI Automation should be easier in .net

Comment: Thank you @Barmak Shemirani, i ll try this!

Comment: I guess question #1 is closed, #2 and #3 remaining.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CB_ADDSTRING` to add items to combo box as follows:

```
IntPtr hwnd_external = FindWindow(IntPtr.Zero, "some window");
IntPtr hcombo = FindWindowEx(hwnd_external, IntPtr.Zero, "ComboBox", IntPtr.Zero);
int sel = SendMessage(hcombo, CB_ADDSTRING, IntPtr.Zero, "Test1");
SendMessage(hcombo, CB_SETCURSEL, sel, IntPtr.Zero);
```

This should work with another process, assuming it's a standard combo box control, but it may not work with some controls, for example some owner draw controls.

```
IntPtr hlist = FindWindowEx(hwnd_external, IntPtr.Zero, "SysListView32", IntPtr.Zero);
```

Adding items to ListView control is more difficult because you need access to memory in the other process.

- Get the process handle from the window
- Call `OpenProcess`
- Allocate memory for `LVITEM` with `VirtualAllocEx`
- Use `WriteProcessMemory` to write to `LVITEM`
- Send `LVM_INSERTITEM` message

Example:

```
DWORD process_id;
HWND hlist = FindWindowEx(hwnd_external, 0, L"SysListView32", 0);
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hlist, &process_id);

HANDLE hprocess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_READ |
    PROCESS_VM_WRITE, FALSE, process_id);
if(!hprocess)
    return 0;

wchar_t text[] = L"new item";
void* pbuf = VirtualAllocEx(hprocess, NULL, sizeof(text), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
WriteProcessMemory(hprocess, pbuf, text, sizeof(text), NULL);

void* pitem = VirtualAllocEx(hprocess, NULL, sizeof(LVITEM), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
LVITEM lvItem = { 0 };
lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_STATE;
lvItem.cchTextMax = wcslen(text);
lvItem.pszText = (wchar_t*)pbuf;
WriteProcessMemory(hprocess, pitem, &lvItem, sizeof(LVITEM), NULL);

SendMessage(hlist, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)(const LV_ITEM*)(pitem));

VirtualFreeEx(hprocess, pitem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
VirtualFreeEx(hprocess, pbuf, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
CloseHandle(hprocess);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Barmak Shemirani i will try this tomorrow! Btw what do you think about my way of solving the problem of choosing an item in the Combobox by WM_KEYUP? is it bad?